# Copy all files from a subfolder to another subfolder of the same name Windows 10

Tags: cmd, command-line, windows-10, batch-processing

So I want to copy all files in `folder_A/theatre` into `folder_B/theatre`,
`folder_A/show` into `folder_B/show` etc.

I have 150 subfolders per parent folder in total, with all subfolders and files uniquely named.

Comment: One wonders which OS this is to be performed on.

Comment: @Roadowl Windows 10 :)